# Kubernetes network policy to filter on both namespaces and pod's labels

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any ability to filter by both namespace **and** pod's labels at the same time?

The example present in documentation at https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/networkpolicies/#the-networkpolicy-resource

```
 - from:
 - namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
     project: myproject
 - podSelector:
    matchLabels:
     role: frontend
```

means that communication is allowed for pods with `role=frontend` **or** from `namespace myproject`.

Is there any way to change that "or" into an "and"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This has been implemented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60452

Currently, there is not yet a way to select certain pod from another namespace. There is an open issue for that https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50451

Comment: Thank you for the issue link.

Comment: This has now been resolved, check out my answer for examples :).

Answer (score 6):

Kubernetes 1.11 and above supports combining podSelector and namespaceSelector with a logical AND:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: database.postgres
  namespace: database
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          namespace: default
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: admin
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

See more details in here: https://medium.com/@reuvenharrison/an-introduction-to-kubernetes-network-policies-for-security-people-ba92dd4c809d/#f416

Comment: The only solution which helped me!

Comment: I'm trying this on 1.16.4 with Calico CNI and it does not seem to work for me. It behaves as OR, traffic from any pod in the namespace or any pod with the labels in other namespaces are allowed. (exactly the same as if I would make two entries of the `namespaceSelector` and the `podSelector`.) Am I running into a bug? I also cannot seem to find this combination in the Kubernetes docs.

Comment: 1) The Kubernetes docs are here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors . 2) It appears I had created my namespace without a label and then Kubernetes goes wonky.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the selectors. Within the API docs for the [NetworkPolicyPeer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.5/#networkpolicypeer-v1beta1) you'll find these descriptions:

**namespaceSelector**

> Selects Namespaces using cluster scoped-labels. This matches all pods in all namespaces selected by this label selector. This field follows standard label selector semantics. If omitted, this selector selects no namespaces. If present but empty, this selector selects all namespaces.

**podSelector**

> This is a label selector which selects Pods in this namespace. This field follows standard label selector semantics. If not provided, this selector selects no pods. If present but empty, this selector selects all pods in this namespace.

Therefore the combinations out of both selectors doesn't really implement a boolean operation and they aim for different scopes (current namespace vs. all other namespaces).

So the only solution for your problem would be to label each pod also with a namespace related label which you could select within the `namespaceSelector`

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. Do you mind explaining it again?

Comment: Your pods would need a label with the namespace in it - so that the `podSelector` can match this label too

Comment: But you will never be able to select a pod from a different namespace, right?

Comment: Not sure what your question relates to ... my answer relates to the initial question where Adam tried to mix two selectors in the context of the `NetworkPolicy` resource.

Comment: I understand that Adam in the initial question wanted to select a certain pod from a different namespace and for that to work you would need to AND the selectors. But I think that that is not possible. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This statement will not work:

```
- from:
- namespaceSelector:
   matchLabels:
    project: myproject
- podSelector:
  matchLabels:
    role: frontend
```

What happens there, if you choose the namespace selector and you put a specific pod to connect to your pod, will not work. Because just specifying the namespace already you opened the whole namespace to connect to your pod. It's useless to put the `podSelector`. An alternative would be to use `ipBlock` but again is not recommended in large clusters because the IP might change.

There is an update on GitHub to fix this problem.